# Why does logarithmic scatter axis not start at zero?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm generating a scatter plot in matplotlib. Everything works fine if I use linear scales.

But since I'm mainly interested in the lower values, I thought I'd use logarithmic scaling. However, even though I have set my x-axis limits explicitly to (0,1), the axis starts at 0.1, so i miss everything below that!

Why does the logarithmic axis not start at zero, and how can I force it to?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.random.randint(1000, size=100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.set_xlim(0,1.2)
ax.set_ylim(0,1000)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter('%1.0f'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))

# this red line at x = 0.1
ax.axvline(x=0.1,color='r')

plt.show()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually logarithmic axes never start at zero because there is no "good" value for `log(0)` on the `x`-axis, because `log(0)==x` only for `x->-infinity`.

Comment: @tcaswell: I took out that part you were referring to. I think his real requirements are still not 100% clear to me, probably that's why I mentioned it initially.

Comment: The math is still wrong, `log(1) = 0`.  Log graphs don't show 0 because `log(x->0) -> -infinity`

Comment: Fixed. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Still have x,0 flipped at the end of the post

Comment: @honk: Thanks. I fixed the problem by using (0.01,1) as limits for x, and replacing any x-values below that with 0.01 for the plot